# Getting better at Geometry - soft question

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry

I am a high school student in the UK (year 12 UK, grade 11 US. I am very interested in maths and so have been doing some STEP papers (2 and 3) in my spare time. I have become reasonably proficient at them, being able now to solve most pure questions in 30-40 minutes. However, I always struggle with the geometry/vectors questions, and have only ever successfully answered a few. I would like to get better at answering these types of questions, as I am currently disproportionately incompetent at them, as well as get better at geometry generally. I do know the basic theorems for olympiads by reading Holton's books on maths olympiads, but the clever tricks required to solve problems are often elusive.

Are there any texts or problem sets that you would recommend?

Any attention given would be massively appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you read the excellent book : "How to solve it" by George Polya, which you might buy on the Internet.

Comment: Read "pathfinder book on Olympiad mathematics" by Vikash Tiwari which you can buy on internet and I will also recommend you to read Book "Introduction to  geometry" by Coxeter here 
 http://personal.cimat.mx:8181/~gil/docencia/2021/geometria2021/[Coxeter]Introduction%20to%20Geometry,2ndEd(1969).pdf

Comment: The "introduction to geometry" not only enhance your geometry capabilities but also increase the Interest and love towards it.